# python one target function attached to three threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a single target function . I create three threads and assign this single target to each of the threads. I pass different slices of the same dataset as input parameter to the threads. I also pass a queue to the thread to get back return values. Inside the threads the queue is getting populated .

My problem is after t.join, I am getting an empty queue for all the three threads.

Question:

1. Is it okay to pass the same target function to multiple threads
2. if the above is okay why am I not getting back the items from the queue

Target function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import threading
import queue

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

class newtxtfeat:

    def __init__(self):

        self.gene_can_list = ['APC','ATM','BMPR1A','BRCA1','BRCA2','CDK4','CDKN2A','CHK2','CREBBP','EGFR','EP300','ETV6','FHIT','FLT3','HRAS','KIT','MET','MLH1','MLL','NTR3','NTRK1','PAX8','PDGFRA','PPARγ','PRCC','PRKAR1A','PTEN','RET','RUNXBP2','STK11','TFE3','TGF-β','TGF-βRII','TP53','WWOX','PALB2','CHEK2','CDH1','BARD1','RAD51C','RAD51D','NBN','NF1']
        self.df_new_text_feat= pd.DataFrame()
        self.data_text = None

    def load_data(self):
        """
            training_text is part of the personel cancer detection dataset that can be downloaded from kaggle
        """
        self.data_text =pd.read_csv("../data/training_text",sep="\|\|",engine="python",names=["ID","TEXT"],skiprows=1)

        self.genr_canc_dict = None

    def fnd_canc_wrd(self,gn_cn_dt,col, tkn, canctcnt, cancntcnt):

        return canctcnt, cancntcnt

    def crea_txt_ft(self,dt_txt_smp, gncanlst,df_new_txtft, opqueue):

        for index, row in dt_txt_smp.iterrows():

            corpora = [row['TEXT']]

            # instantiate the vectorizer object
            cvec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', lowercase=False )

            # convert the documents into a document-term matrix
            wm = cvec.fit_transform(corpora)

            # retrieve the terms found in the corpora
            tokens = cvec.get_feature_names()

            # the following counts can be intialized to any constant
            canc_tech_count = 0
            canc_nontech_count = 0
            gene_count = 0
            protin_count = 0
            mutant_count = 0
            tumor_count = 0
            leukemia_count = 0
            amino_count = 0
            spec_gene_count = 0


            for i in range(0,len(tokens)):
                onechar = tokens[i][0]
                if onechar == 'a':     
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_a', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)

                elif onechar == 'b':        

                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_b', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)

                elif onechar == 'c':     
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_c', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'd':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_d', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'e':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_e', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'f':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_f', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'g':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_g', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'h':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_h', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'i':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_i', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'j':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_j', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)


                elif onechar == 'k':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_k', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'l':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_l', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'm':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_m', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'n':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_n', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        


                elif onechar == 'o':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_o', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)


                elif onechar == 'p':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_p', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)

                elif onechar == 'q':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_q', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)

                elif onechar == 'r':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_r', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 's':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_s', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 't':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_t', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)

                elif onechar == 'u':                
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_u', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'v':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_v', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'w':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_w', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'x':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_x', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'y':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_y', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                elif onechar == 'z':        
                    canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count = self.fnd_canc_wrd(self.genr_canc_dict, 'col_z', tokens[i],canc_tech_count,canc_nontech_count)        

                else:

                    canc_nontech_count += 1

                if tokens[i] in gncanlst:
                    spec_gene_count += 1

                if tokens[i] == 'gene':
                    gene_count += 1
                elif tokens[i] == 'protein':
                    protin_count += 1
                elif tokens[i] in ['mutation','mutant']:
                    mutant_count += 1
                elif tokens[i] == 'tumor':
                    tumor_count  += 1
                elif tokens[i] == 'leukemia':
                    leukemia_count += 1            
                elif tokens[i] == 'amino':
                    amino_count += 1


                #print(canc_tech_count)  
                #print('not found',canc_nontech_count )
                #print(i)
            df_new_txtft =df_new_txtft.append({'canc_tech_cnt':canc_tech_count,'canc_tech_rto': canc_tech_count / i, \
            'tot_wrds':i,'canc_gene_cnt':spec_gene_count,'gene_cnt':gene_count,'protin_cnt':protin_count,\
            'muta_cnt':mutant_count,'tumor_cnt':tumor_count,'leuk_cnt':leukemia_count,'amino_cnt':amino_count}, ignore_index=True) 

        opqueue.put(df_new_txtft)

if __name__ == "__main__"   :

    newfeat = newtxtfeat()
    newfeat.load_data()

    newfeat.q1df = queue.Queue()
    newfeat.q2df = queue.Queue()
    newfeat.q3df = queue.Queue()

    newfeat.df_new_txtft_1 = pd.DataFrame()
    newfeat.df_new_txtft_2 = pd.DataFrame()
    newfeat.df_new_txtft_3 = pd.DataFrame()

    newfeat.df_text_1 = newfeat.data_text[1:11]
    newfeat.df_text_2 = newfeat.data_text[11:21]
    newfeat.df_text_3 = newfeat.data_text[21:31]

    lst1 = newfeat.gene_can_list
    lst2 = newfeat.gene_can_list
    lst3 = newfeat.gene_can_list

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=newfeat.crea_txt_ft, args=(newfeat.df_text_1, lst1 ,newfeat.df_new_txtft_1,newfeat.q1df))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=newfeat.crea_txt_ft, args=(newfeat.df_text_2, lst2 ,newfeat.df_new_txtft_2,newfeat.q2df))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=newfeat.crea_txt_ft, args=(newfeat.df_text_3, lst3 ,newfeat.df_new_txtft_3,newfeat.q3df))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()

    while not newfeat.q1df.empty():
        newfeat.df_new_txtft_1 = newfeat.q1df.get()

    while not newfeat.q2df.empty():
        newfeat.df_new_txtft_2 = newfeat.q2df.get()


    while True:
        if newfeat.q3df.empty():
            print('Third Queue is empty and closed . Exiting thread.')
            break
        try:
            newfeat.df_new_txtft_3 = newfeat.q3df.get()
        except:
            continue

    if (not newfeat.df_new_txtft_1 ) and  (not newfeat.df_new_txtft_2) and (not newfeat.df_new_txtft_3) :
        newfeat.df_new_text_feat = pd.concat([newfeat.df_new_txtft_1,newfeat.df_new_txtft_2,newfeat.df_new_txtft_3],ignore_index=True)

        print(newfeat.df_new_text_feat.info())
        print(newfeat.df_new_text_feat.shape)
```

I expect the three queues to return back with the updated values from the thread.

Actually, I am being returned an empty queue.

Comment: Can you post a Minimal version of your code that a) shows the problem, and b) is complete (no pseudo-code!) so others can run the code themselves? Https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve As it’s not obvious that the number of threads is significant, maybe a version with just one thread would show the problem. Or two threads?

Comment: Minimal code has been updated for the issue. the primary dataset(training_text) needs to be downloaded from the personel cancer detection competition from kaggle website

Comment: I doubt that’s _Minimal_ - can’t you reproduce the problem without doing all that stuff which is really just noise - write something that takes input and pushes results to the queue, get that working, then add back in your real processing need. Does the target function actually put anything on the queue? Have you tried getting just one thread to show the problem (or work!)?